# why column is changing to data.frame after using of match in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

One columns is changing to data.frame after the use of match condition in R. 
Can any one let me know why a column is updating to factor to data.frame after updating ?

```
a<-data.frame(columnB=sample(1:20,20,replace = F),
              columnC=sample(4:80,20,replace = F))
d<-data.frame(columnE=letters[1:20],
              columnF=sample(1:20,20,replace = F))
a$columnB<-d[match(a$columnB,d$columnF),]
str(a)

Output :
> str(a)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ columnB:'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ columnE: Factor w/ 20 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 18 8 1 19 16 3 4 15 17 5 ...
  ..$ columnF: int  6 20 12 11 13 1 7 19 14 8 ...
 $ columnC: int  69 6 37 80 55 49 4 5 44 76 ...
```

1.please clarify how it get resolved to make data frame column to normal columns 
2.is there any method to easy match and update of column in **a table** based on **d table**.

Comment: Can you show expected output? Please set a seed and use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create you dataframes.

Comment: `d[match(a$columnB,d$columnF),]` is a `data.frame`, so you're assigning a `data.frame` to a column

Comment: do you need `a$columnB <- d$columnE[match(a$columnB,d$columnF)]`

Comment: thanks to all the comments...got the solution